# Pass in complex type parameters and set default values in MVC Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My complex type model:

```
public class User
{
    public string name {set{name=value;}get{return name??"";}}
}
```

My MVC Action:

```
public JsonResult GetUser(User user)
{
   //do something
}
```

Then wrong here:

```
“System.StackOverflowException”
```

What do I have to do to be correct?

Thanks!~

Answer (score 2):

Wrong is set{name=value;} which is calling setter again. You should create a separate property and use it inside setter and getter.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User
{
   private string _name;

    public string name {set{_name=value;}get{return _name??"";}}
}
```

Comment: (Properties usually goes with Pascal Case, so it's better to use Name instead of name)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverlow exception is here, when value set to property which setter set value to itself.

I though this is obvious and compiler could check this.

```
public string name {set{name=value;}get{return name??"";}}
```